# Is there any diffrence between Continue and GoTo Start in this code?

Tags: .net, vb.net, syntax, coding-style, continue

```
    While True
Start:
        Continue While
        GoTo(Start)
    End While
```

NOTE: I know GoTo will never get reach in this example. I am just wondering if there is any computational difference between using GoTo (X) and (Exit / Continue) statements?  I tend to like to use GoTo statements even where Continue or Exit would suffice. Is this bad style? I don't see GoTo in other programmers code very often.

EDIT: As people kindly pointed out the GoTo would not evaluate the condition on a conditional while loop. Which leads me to ask would the following two pieces of code compile down to the exact same CLR code:

```
Dim x as Integer = 0
While x < 5
    Continue
End While
```

And

```
    Dim x As Integer = 0
JumpPoint:
    If x < 5 Then
        GoTo JumpPoint
    End If
```

Comment: What do you mean by "computational"?

Comment: GoTo is generally considered bad practice as it can easily lead to code that is very hard to follow.

Comment: Odd? That is why I like GoTo because I think it is easier to follow. At least if you use good LabelNames.

Comment: Why don't you just make a test assembly with that code and run the MSIL disassembler on it so you can see for yourself?  It's very easy to do and it should be easy to follow the MSIL code for such a simple example.

Comment: Because I did not know such a thing existed! Thanks for pointing that out and I will go check it out now.

Comment: Using goto is considered bad practice. However, the irony is, whenever you use an "Exit For" statement, the VB.NET compiler simply replaces it with a goto statement. You can see this using Reflector or dotPeek or some other .NET decompiler. I find this to be very ironic and kind of funny!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is one little difference: For `Continue`, the condition of the while loop is reevaluated, `GoTo` simple continues execution from the Start label without looking at the while condition.

```
Start:

    GoTo(Start)
```

Would be the same as

```
While True
    Continue While
End While
```

in terms of "what happens". But as soon as a condition is introduced, the `GoTo` wouldn't do the same.

---

For your updated question: Yes, there is one difference, again. The first statement includes the `Continue` which does (basically) the same as the  `GoTo`. But what is not included in your example is a case where the `Continue` or `GoTo` is not called because of any operation which took place in between. If `Continue` is skipped, the `End While` will just loop over to the next `While` evaluation and run.

Comment: @vanattab: *dont'* edit your question with another question.  Post a second question instead.

Answer (score 1):

There's a difference if any evaluation is done in the loop condition, such as:

```
While var < 5
```

By using `goto(start)` the value of `var` is not evaluated again.

As for coding style, nobody will stop you from using `goto` but `continue` and `exit` already jump to well defined code points, reducing the usefulness of `goto` in many cases.